# Issue regarding loop to find Root mean square error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sensors

I have 6 different data sets from sensor and I want to find out the Root mean Square error but of the limited signal with limits means RMSE of sig_diff_lim.

I have tried to apply loop but it’s not working can anybody tell me where I am at fault.

Thanks in anticipation.

```
 clc

 drv(1)=load('a.mat');
 drv(2)=load('b.mat');
 drv(3)=load('c.mat');
 drv(4)=load('d.mat');
 drv(5)=load('e.mat');
 drv(6)=load('h.mat');

 for i= 1:numel(drv)
   t=drv(i).T;
   ref=drv(i).P;
   lws=drv(i).SWA;

   sig_diff(i,:) =lws(i)-ref(i);

   swvel_thres=10;
   vehvel=30;   
   SAmax=90;


   sig_diff_lim(i,:)=sig_diff((lws(i)<SAmax)&(lws(i)>-SAmax)&(swav(i)<swvel_thres)&(vel(i)>vehvel));



   square_error(i,:) = (sig_diff_lim(i)).^2;
   mse(i,:)=  mean(square_error(i));
   rmse(i,:) = sqrt(mse(i));

end
rmse 
mse
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the error? What size should `square_error` be? Is it a 6*n matrix or 6*1? What output is unexpected?

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply. Please have a look at attached picture above actually its dimension issue that I am facing so i am confused whether I have correctly applied command within the loop for matrix dimensions.

Comment: And Square error should be 6*1 so that it finds square error for every data set means for data set 1 ,2,3,4,5,6 and then displays them separately in command window .

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is lws_7? where were sig_diff_lim and  sig_diff_lim defined? Can you give the definition/sizes of all the variales involved? A simple approach to debug that will be to print out the sizes of them separatley, this will give you an idea of what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks to you for reply . Really sorry its actually lws i unfortunately placed in code while uploading but i have updated in my code.Sig_diff_lim is actually signal difference with limits applied like swvel ,vehvel,SAmax  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that while assigning to `sig_diff_lim(i,:)` requires a row vector of size `1*n`, the matrix that is returned by

```
vec=sig_diff((lws_7(i)<SAmax)&(lws_7(i)>-SAmax)&(swav(i)<swvel_thres)&(vel(i)>vehvel))
```

is of a different size.

**Edit**

- First, are you sure that `sig_diff((lws(i)...` shouldn't be `sig_diff(i,:)((lws(i)....` on the assignemnt line?
- Now, try **element-wise** multiplication (operator .* ) between `sig_diff` (or `sig_diff(i,:))`, depending on your answer to my previous point) with your logical indexing, like this:

  ```
  sig_diff.*((lws(i)<...   %%%% instead of sig_diff((lws(i)<...
  %%% or 
  sig_diff(i,:).*(lws(i)<...
  ```

I think that should do the trick.

- Regardless of whether or not this worked, try this example to understand what is going on with that sort of logical indexing:

  ```
  >> t=[1 2 3 5 7;1 5 6 8 10];
  >> t(1,:)(l<7  & l>-7)
  ans =

  1   2   3   5

  >> t(1,:)(l<7  & l>-2)
  ans =

  1   2   5
  ```

Of course, in this example, `t` is fixed while the thresholds are changing , while in your code the matrix itself is changing. But it shows you that your indexing will return matrices of variable length.

But, with the solution I proposed above,

```
>> t(1,:).*(l<7  & l>-2)
>> t(1,:).*(l<7  & l>-7)
```

are both of size `5*1`.

Comment: signal_diff_lim(i,:)=sig_diff((lws<SAmax)&(lws>-SAmax)&(swav<swvel_thres)&(vel>vehvel)); Actually I want to save data in some matrix everytime when new drive data is loaded . I will speak the truth with u unfortunately above mentioned solution did not worked is not there any way that sig_diff_lim is calculated for every data means for data 1 ,2 ,3 ,4,5 ,6 because i am getting dimension mismatch .

Comment: Sorry for late reply as i was trying out some stuffs but remained unsuccessful.

Comment: @Peter sorry, didn't grasp that sentence "is not there any way that sig_diff_lim is calculated ...."  .  Did you print the size of sig_diff? when/where/how did you initialize it?

Comment: I make it simple I am not getting values for all 6 drives in vec after evrytime i is updated means for i=1 i need vec to get updated and for i=2 i need vec to get updated again but with the above mentioned command it is not saving values every time i is changed means 1,2,3,etc

Comment: I make it simple.
I have reference signal and data from sensor for 6 different drives.
I want to calculate RMSE for signal difference means ref-sensor data but with some limitations.
Sig_diff_lim is actually signal difference with limitations.
I have tried to apply loop that should save data in a matrix for every data like 1,2,3,4,5,6 means for every changing I values I want to calculate RMSE.
I am really sorry for inconvenience. 
I hope I remained able to explain u the exact situation.

Comment: @Peter I think I found the problem! An element-wise multiplication should fix it! I edited my answer, I hope it will help. Let me know :)

Comment: Ash thanks a lot for all ur help . It worked great . Have a nice time and sorry for delayed feedback .